# Can we say "same to you" in response to "nice to meet you"?

Tags: differences, word-usage

Is it ok to respond with "same to you" when someone says Nice to meet you ?
I am getting confused because "you too" can be interchangeably used for "same to you".

Comment: It would be slightly odd because the person speaking to you is referencing himself:  he means "It's nice *for me* to meet you," and your expected response would have to mean "It's the same for me in meeting you."  You might accomplish this by saying "Nice to meet you, too" or "Likewise for me."  When the person references you instead of himself, e.g, "Congratulations on graduating from school," meaning congratulations *to you*, then you can return the expression by saying "Same to you."  (Assuming, of course, that the person you're talking to has just graduated as well.)

Comment: For the record, I am not the downvoter.

Comment: You could also say: [The pleasure is (all) mine](http://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/71620-The-pleasure-is-mine), "It's been my pleasure", or [Likewise](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/likewise) (informal)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't really work because, "Same to you!" is commonly used by children to return an insult, e.g.

*"You're stupid!"*

*"Same to you!"*

You can say, "Same here!" but that is somewhat informal. It wouldn't be suitable for most business meetings in my opinion.

*"Nice to meet you!"*

*"Same here!"*

**My suggestion**

*"Nice to meet you!"*

*"Nice to meet you too!"*

Answer (score 0):

It's not really something a native speaker would say because it is, as @deadrat has said not semantically correct.

Incidentally, strictly speaking, 'nice to  meet you' isn't the way you should greet someone if you're polite - that phrase should be reserved for when you are ending the meeting. For a cold meeting (where the people involvved don't know each other) it should be 'how do you do?' or [a more logical alternative](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/299910/what-should-i-say-when-meet-a-person-for-the-first-time).