# What should I say when meet a person for the first time?

Tags: sentence, sentence-patterns

What should I say at the end of the meeting, assuming that I've never meet that person before?

Should it be something like:

> "It was a pleasure to meet you."

or just

> "Nice to meet you."?

Comment: Why not wing it?  "I've enjoyed our chat."  "I hope we can talk some more in the future."  "It's been most enjoyable talking to you."

Comment: WTF, why did you put on hold the question?

Answer (score 1):

> "Nice to meet you"

is more something you'd say just after the introduction, and isn't really suitable for the end.

> "It was nice meeting you"

would be fine, but

> "It was a pleasure to meet you"

after a meeting may be a better choice as it has a more positive connotation.